# Making a list of a list of characters

Tags: java, list, arraylist, char

I want to make an ArrayList of a list of characters.
Right now I have this code:

```
Scanner scannerMcScannersonTM = new Scanner(System.in); //This is trademarked.
    String[] inputs = new String[5];
    List<List<char>> list = new ArrayList<List<char>>();  
    for(int i =0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter pair number " + (i+1) + " separated by a space");
        inputs[i] = scannerMcScannersonTM.nextLine();
        for(int j = 0; j < inputs[i].length(); i++){
            list[i] = inputs[i].toChar(); //it is clear that I don't know what I am doing lol

        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: Having `ArrayList<Character>` is unusual which makes your question look like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Normally when we want to gather some characters we use `String` or `char[]`. Can you explain why you think you need it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner scannerMcScannersonTM = new Scanner(System.in); //This is trademarked.

//you do not need this if you know the size and not using inputs afterwards.
String[] inputs = new String[5]; 

// java collections can only contain non-primitive types, hence, use Character instead of char
List<List<Character>> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter pair number " + (i+1) + " separated by a space");

    String inputs[i] = scannerMcScannersonTM.nextLine();

    // .toCharArray() method on string does exactly what it says.
    // and Arrays.asList(.. an array ..) will convert the array to a List!
    list.add(Arrays.asList(inputs[i].toCharArray())); 
}
```